# How to make a relation between two objects in database JAVA

Tags: java, database, oop

I am currently trying to create a relation between my Student class and my Discipline class. This is what I am doing:

@Service
public class StudentRegistrationService implements ApplicationRunner {

```
private final StudentRepository repository;
private final DisciplineRepository repository1;

public StudentRegistrationService(StudentRepository repository, DisciplineRepository repository1) {
    this.repository = repository;
    this.repository1 = repository1;
}

@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {


    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] split = input.split(" ");

        String command = split[0];

        switch (command.toUpperCase()) {
            case "END":
                System.out.println("bye bye");
                return;
            case "STUDLIST":
                printAllStudents();
                break;
            case "STUDNEW":
                String[] studentDetails = Arrays.copyOfRange(split, 1, split.length);
                createNewStudent(studentDetails);
                break;
            case "DISCLIST":
                printAllDisciplines();
                break;
            case "DISCNEW":
                String[] disciplineDetails = Arrays.copyOfRange(split, 1, split.length);
                createNewDiscipline(disciplineDetails);
                break;
            case "STUDDISC":
                String[] studentAndDisciplineId = Arrays.copyOfRange(split, 1, split.length);
                studendAndDiscipline(studentAndDisciplineId);

                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("UNKNOWN command, try again!");
                break;
        }

    }

}


private void createNewDiscipline(String[] details) {
    int hours=Integer.parseInt(details[1]);
    repository1.save(new Discipline(details[0],hours));
}

private void printAllDisciplines() {

    Iterable<Discipline> allDisciplines = repository1.findAll();

    for (Discipline discipline : allDisciplines) {
        System.out.println(discipline);
    }
}

private void createNewStudent(String[] details) {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(details[1], dtf);
    repository.save(new Student(details[0],localDate));
}

private void printAllStudents() {

    Iterable<Student> allStudents = repository.findAll();

    for (Student student : allStudents) {
        System.out.println(student);
    }
}

private void studendAndDiscipline(String[] details) {
    int studentId=Integer.parseInt(details[1]);
    int disciplineId=Integer.parseInt(details[2]);
    Student student=repository.findById(studentId);
    Discipline discipline=repository1.findById(disciplineId);
    student.addDiscipline(discipline);
}
```

}

In studentAndDiscipline I have to create a relation between a student and a discipline both by ID, but I am doing it wrong. I tried using Optional<>, but it doesn't work either.

My Student class:
@Entity
class Student {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;


private String name;
private LocalDate enrollmentDate;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
List<Discipline> disciplines;


private Student() {
    // Required by Hibernate
}
public Student(String name, LocalDate enrollmentDate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.enrollmentDate = enrollmentDate;
}

void addDiscipline(Discipline discipline) {
    this.disciplines.add(discipline);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", enrollmentDate=" + enrollmentDate +
            ", disciplines=" + disciplines +
            '}';
}
```

}

My Discipline Class: 
@Entity
class Discipline {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;


String name;
int credits;

private Discipline() {
    // Required by Hibernate
}
public Discipline(String name, int credits) {
    this.name = name;
    this.credits = credits;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Discipline{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", credits=" + credits +
            '}';
}
```

}

My StudentRepository:

```
interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Integer> {
```

}

My DisciplineRepository:

```
interface DisciplineRepository extends CrudRepository<Discipline, Integer> {
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void studendAndDiscipline(String[] details) {
    int studentId=Integer.parseInt(details[1]);
    int disciplineId=Integer.parseInt(details[2]);
    Student student=repository.findById(studentId);
    Discipline discipline=repository1.findById(disciplineId);
    student.addDiscipline(discipline);
}
```

`Discipline discipline=repository1.findById(disciplineId);`, is not right. `findById(ID id)` would return `Optional<T>` type, you need to use `get()` to get the T. 
 And you should make sure discipline is not null. At least you need to check it like

```
Student student=repository.findById(studentId).get();
Discipline discipline=repository1.findById(disciplineId).get();
if (discipline != null) {
    student.addDiscipline(discipline);
    System.out.println("Adding discipline to student.");
}
```

If you are sure discipline is not null, you need to check addDiscipline() implementation.

Comment: The problem is that the program doesn't compile at all. At Student student and Discipline discipline I get incompatible types. Student student says required Student, found Optional and Discipline discipline says required Discipline, found optional.

Comment: please add Student, Discipline and StudentRepository

Comment: I have added it to my original post. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: thanks a lot. It now compiles, but I get "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2"

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 means you are getting `details[2]`, the third element of array, while `details` only contains 2 elements, not 3.